# Word for a belief in extra-terrestrial rights

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that means, "**a belief in goodness and liberty toward sentient aliens.**"  The use of "humanitarian" doesn't seem to fit due to the use of "human" in it, and I am not entirely convinced that "xenotarian" is a valid word (although it might be.)

Comment: Let me guess: you're writing a science-fiction story? In any case, I think there *ought* to be such a word, but I've never heard of it.

Comment: `Xenotarian` is 1. a barbarism (`xenos` is from Greek, but the `-arian[us]` ending is from Latin; it would be `alienarian`), 2. only refers to outsiders / foreigners (`xenos` means "foreigner").

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I almost never ask questions I honestly "need" to know.  Just sort of came to me in idle curiosity, to be perfectly honest.  Nonetheless, I think it's a valid question.

Comment: I posit Philzenthropic/Philzenthropism as a catch-all neologism - however, this could apply to not only sentient, but proto-sentient and non-sentient beings.

Comment: Oh, I have no objection to the question. I was just speculating on your reason for asking! :-)  Pure curiosity is as valid a reason as any!

Comment: Wouldn't you rather be interested in a word that meant "a belief in goodness and liberty toward sentient *beings*" instead of limiting it to "aliens"?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Perhaps so.

Comment: Extraterrestrialitarian? Nice little word that sort of rolls off the tongue (and lands in a ditch after having stumbled over its own legs three times on the way down).

Comment: Xenotarian is the best you'll get, and it's "what would be used in scifi"

Comment: the "extra-" forms **are only relevant in a scifi millieu looking from Earth (or another 'non-contacted' planet) outwards**.  once "everyone knows" about different sentient beings, the "extra-" part makes no sense.  it would be Xeno-some-other-cool-word-parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing I can think of is xenophilia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophilia

More generally, allophilia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophilia

"Xenotarian" sounds like a person who only eats aliens, haha.

Comment: The *-philia* and *-phile* suffixes suggest to me objectification rather than egalitarian treatment. The former also has shades of a kink/fetish connotation. That said, *allo-* or *pan-* are on the right track.

Comment: Yes, these are the **opposites** of the word being sought.

Comment: @JoeBlow I know these aren't *exactly* what the OP is looking for (because I don't think it exists), but how are they the *opposite*? From the links above: Xenophily or xenophilia means an affection for unknown/foreign objects or peoples. It is the opposite of xenophobia or xenophoby. Allophilia is having a positive attitude for a group that is not one's own. The term derived from Greek words meaning "liking or love of the other". It is a framework for understanding effective intergroup leadership and is conceptualized as a measurable state of mind with tangible consequences

Answer (score 3):

In Buddhism it is frequently used the expression "sentient beings". [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentience)
I think you could use the same expression.

If you want to emphasize the E.T. nature perhaps you could use the expression "Non-Earthly" as in "...toward all Non-Earthly sentient beings" I don't think there is a single word expression for this.

> Freedom is the right of all sentient beings. *Optimus Prime*